# Cannot log into Bios menu

Tags: debian, bios, hdmi, touchpad

I have two problems, it seems they are linked. I don't know how to proceed and fix it.

1) I cannot log into the BIOS, after hooking up the HDMI port to a LG Smart TV monitor.

Initially I was able to enter the BIOS. Now, I see "_" in the blank screen. I am able to log into the Debian 10.  I am using a 64 bit distro.  I have only Debian 10 in my machine. Any way to resolve the issue?

2) The touchpad does not work. Mysteriously, I don't recall what I changed in the BIOS, my touchpad started to work. Now with the disappearance of the BIOS altogether, the touchpad also does not work.

$lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

$lspci -nn
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller [8086:a368] (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller [8086:a369] (rev 10)

$grep Name /proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
N: Name="ELAN0504:01 04F3:3091 Touchpad"

$xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)] 
⎜ ↳ ELAN0504:01 04F3:3091 Touchpad id=14 [slave pointer (2)]

Comment: Hi, Is this the way to contact you? @Tetsujin. I am new to this forum. I just deleted the two previous post, as he voted to close it. I didn't see a way someone can do it, I found a button to delete the posts. Anyway, I will edit and polish the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: BIOS is not related to operating system at all. Hook up a standard monitor, find the keyboard key for your PC to enter BIOS, start up, press that key repeatedly during startup and enter BIOS.  Can you resolve what you need in BIOS?

Comment: @John: In my acer nitro 5 laptop, F2 key is used to enter the BIOS. I don't know what happened, I cannot loginto the BIOS even without connecting any HDMI monitor or TV. However, I am able to log into to the laptop.

Comment: Log in, make sure the F keys are locked to  be F1, F2 etc, restart and try again. Try the keystroke combination that gets F1, F2 when you are logged in. Perhaps call Acer Support

Comment: @John: I called the Acer, but they say Windows operating system is tied to the BIOS, since I have removed the Windows OS, they cannot help.

Comment: @John: I tried F1...n keys, but no luck

Comment: I think the issue must be an Acer design problem

Comment: @Golam The support can and should help you accessing the firmware (UEFI,  you don't have BIOS) regardless of the OS. You could need to reinstall Windows and for that you'd need to access the firmware settings most of the times. And I don't believe they actually used the words you said they did, customers tend to misunderstand a lot when calling tech support and many people just can't explain themselves properly, that's what I suspect happened.